# how to handle rasa form confirmation or denying from actions.py

Tags: rasa-core, rasa

based on the story below:

```
## certif deny_repeat_affirm_stop
* greet
  - utter_greet
* request_certificate
  - certificate_form
  - form{"name": "certificate_form"}
  - form{"name": null}
  - utter_did_that_help
* deny
  - utter_ask_again
* request_certificate
  - certificate_form
  - form{"name": "certificate_form"}
  - form{"name": null}
  - utter_did_that_help
* affirm
  - utter_noworries
* goodbye
  - utter_goodbye
  - action_restart
```

i need to post (rest api) the form to an service, how can i do that from actions.py when the user affirms:

> *affirm

im looking for a trick or something can help me to read the ***affirm** in actions.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom [actions](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/rasa-sdk/#actions) for that.

Your domain.yml file should look like:

```
intents:
    - affirm

actions:
    - action_affirm
```

Your stories.md file should look like:

```
* affirm
    - action_affirm
```

You actions.py file should look like:

```
from rasa_core_sdk import Action
from rasa_core_sdk.events import SlotSet

class ActionAffirm(Action):
    def name(self):
        return 'action_affirm'

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):

            #Do Something you want


        ...
```

Comment: thank you very much, really solved my problem without breaking the logic which am using